# CAML Query in Search Display Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, caml-query, display-template

I have a search result web part based on a display template I made up.
I created an action to had items as favorites.
This way they appear first in the search result web part and they have a full star icon. Other items have an empty star and appear after favorites items.

[image: full star]

and

[image: empty star]

**How I made it:**

All my items have a column "FavoriteMembers" which is a people picker with multiple selection. If current user is in the field then he have a full star, if not he have an empty star. I used a managed property to do it.

I manage to update items from display template to enable user to add or remove favorite on clic on the star. (It updates my item well, in real time)

**My problem:**

If user refresh his browser, item will keeps is old favorite status until the Shareoint search crawled the item again. In SharePoint Online, it takes between 15min and 6 hours (my observation and [others](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/10/waiting-for-search-crawl-in-office-365.html)).

**The solution I'm trying to use:**

CAML Query
I want to use a caml query to retrieve the "FavoriteMembers"column content in real time and update the star icon.

I already use CAML Query on other projects and managed to make it works.
This time, it's the first time I'm trying to make it in a display template but query keep going in the failed part.

**My Code:**

```
function ListItems(){
    var clientcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(currentItemList);
    clientcontext.load(list);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>'+ currentItemTitle +'</Value></Contains></Where></View>');
    var collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientcontext.load(collListItem);

    var currentUser = clientcontext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    clientcontext.load(currentUser);

    clientcontext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        // some more script
    }, function () {
        console.log("alert");
    });
}
```

Any advice ?
Can someone confirm I can use CAML Query in a display template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to make it work with CAML Query so I decided to use REST API.

**Getting FavoriteMembers field value with REST API**

```
$.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + title + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var object = data.d.results;
                if (object[0].FavoriteMembersStringId!=null) {
                    var array = object[0].FavoriteMembersStringId.results;
                    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++ ) {
                        //if one id in the array is userID, then he has the item as favorite
                        if(array[j]==userID){
                            console.log(title + " is a favorite of " + name);
                            //Then input code to show a full star
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            });
```

I had another problem when two users were updating the FavoriteMembers field at the same time. I managed to solve it the same way. If you need more information about this, feel free to contact me.